# Making an imageboard with Rails, what controllers to add?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controllers

I am making my first RoR application and I am a bit confused with planning it out ahead of time.

It will be an anonymous imageboard (like 4chan) where people can make threads across multiple boards and attach images to their posts. They won't need to register and can post anonymously.

Now I am not sure how to implement it, I am guessing there has to be an admin user who will be able to create new boards and delete threads, right? So far I have planned the following controllers:

- PostsController
- UsersController (can I define the admin user here or should I make a separate controller?)
- ThreadsController
- BoardsController

Does this seem okay to you?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planning ahead of time for everything you will need goes against what Ruby on Rails philosophy is to begin with. Ruby on Rails firmly believes in Test Driven Development or TDD.

In that sense, the tests will actually drive your design, starting from unit tests all the way to functional testing. I.e. don't try to anticipate all controller/models from the start. Try to use TDD to let you help design the system, it is a good practice and if you don't know 100% the path you want to follow, it will help you somewhat make your system a bit more robust because of the test harness.

Try to follow this before you start your application. Good luck.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html

Comment: Thank you, I'll do that!

Comment: TDD is not really that firmly believed in the Rails community. DHH thinks it would drag you when you are not 100% sure what you want, because you will do lots of changes.

Comment: I use TDD to drive my design, part of TDD is not being 100% sure of your architecture, and adding test coverage as you go along. It's not always possible of course, and not always practical, so its' always a pragmatic balance.